# bootstrap dynamic dropdown in list-group

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, list, dropdown

I'm trying to build a list-group, with each item in the list have an icon which will trigger a dropdown menu. I have a few problems how to position the dropdown, also the glyphicon is not visible at all, unless I put text in the button, and then it has a bad position.

Also I want to build and position the dropdown dynamically with javascript, but first I need to see one that is position correctly, then I will do all the JS DOM work..
Thanks for help!

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24900/

Some code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <a href="#">option</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>ICON</button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
              <a href="#">option</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div></li>
          </ul>

</div> <!--.col-sm-4 -->          
<div class="col-sm-8">

</div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the version of bootstrap css to a cdn version which includes the glyphicons. I have then moved the anchor element next to the icon which I believe is what you're looking for. I also removed your custom css which was causing a layout issue.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></i>
        <a href="#">option</a>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24902/

Comment: thanks, it does looks better. I do want the icon to be floated near the text, (float right), I can do that, but I dont know how to position the button to open bellow the icon.

Comment: *FIX: to open the dropdown bellow the icon (can't edit the comment)

Comment: It does if I'm not mistaken, I must be misunderstanding

Comment: It does now, but I want the icon to be floated right (the icon should be against the text, not before the text). And then, I want the dropdown to be under the icon (right aligned). That's what i've tried in my fiddle